# Cardslib round corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, cardslib

I have two projects where I create a set of custom `cards` extending the `card` class, and then I insert them into a `StaggeredView`.

My problem is that in one of these projects the cards corners are automatically rounded, while on the other one not!

Moreover in the second project the scroll occurs in fits and starts!

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.staggered_grid);

    List<Tour> data = createList(10);

    ArrayList<Card> cardes = initCards(data);

    mCardArrayAdapter = new CardGridStaggeredArrayAdapter(ListViewPrenota.this, cardes);

    CardGridStaggeredView mGridView = (CardGridStaggeredView)
            ListViewPrenota.this.findViewById(R.id.carddemo_extras_grid_stag);

    if (mGridView != null) {
        mGridView.setAdapter(mCardArrayAdapter);
    }
}


private ArrayList<Card> initCards(List<Tour> data){

    ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= data.size()-1; i++ ){
        DeviceCardList card = new DeviceCardList(this, R.layout.cardslib_inner_layout, data.get(i));

        cards.add(card);
    }
    return cards;
}
```

`DeviceCardList`: [class](http://pastie.org/private/pqrj5pt7vgf1ayfqrxclmq)

`cardslib_inner_layout`: [xml file](http://pastie.org/private/p5ekdhyhzjlqokpa9l3cgg)

`staggered_view.xml`: [xml file](http://pastie.org/private/aixumi2989ccfppcaowqeq)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it! 
It turns out that in order to set the cards' corners with cardslib, it is necessary to OVERRIDE this value:

```
<dimen name="cardview_default_radius">yourRadius</dimen>
<dimen name="card_background_default_radius">"yourRadius"</dimen>
```

from this file: [dimens.xml](https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/library-core/src/main/res/values/dimens.xml)

For me it was only necessary to override `card_background_default_radius`